# Can I install Ubuntu touch desktop on termux

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can I install Ubuntu touch desktop on termux ?

Or is there any method to have something like mobile desktop on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

[Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en_US&gl=US) is an android terminal emulator. Ubuntu-touch ([UBPorts](https://ubports.com/)) is a now unrelated to [Canonical](https://canonical.com/) alternative mobile operating system. So, the answer to the first question is no. The second question is unclear to me.

Comment: The second question probably means something like "How to install Ubuntu Touch UI in regular Ubuntu?"

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch is not a terminal, or something you install to run on your Terminal, it's an alternative operating system to Android, it's the version of Ubuntu for smartphones and tablets.

You can learn more about [Ubuntu Touch](https://ubuntu-touch.io/).